# Python tkinter change variable label state and statusbar

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I do have a little problem here. It's about the exchange of variables of a label in TKinter. My program won't refresh the value's.

```
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,**kw):
         Frame.__init__(self,parent,**kw)
         self.x = None
         self.directory = None
         self.autostate = None
         self.state = "closed"
         self.GUI2()

     def state(self):
         #change states
         self.stateVar="open"
         self.statusbar = "Status: Opening gate..."

         #update tkinter
         self.group.update_idletasks()
         self.w.update_idletasks()

     def GUI2(self):

         self.statusbar = "Status:..."

         # menu left
         self.menu_left = tk.Frame(root, width=150, bg="red", bd=1, relief=RIDGE)
         self.menu_left_upper = tk.Frame(self.menu_left, width=300, height=900, bg="#C0C0C0")
         self.menu_left_lower = tk.Frame(self.menu_left, width=300, bd=1, relief=GROOVE)

         self.label1 = tk.Label(self.menu_left_lower, relief=FLAT, bg="blue" )
         self.button1 = Button(self.menu_left_lower, text="RUN")
         self.test = tk.Label(self.menu_left_upper, text="info", bg="#C0C0C0")


         self.menu_left_upper.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=TRUE)
         self.menu_left_lower.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=FALSE)

         # right area
         self.some_title_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="#dfdfdf", bd=1, relief=RIDGE)
         self.some_title = tk.Label(self.some_title_frame, text="some title", bg="#dfdfdf")
         self.text_area = Listbox(root, width=50, height=10, background="#ffffff", relief=GROOVE)

         #Label and Button
         self.group = LabelFrame(self.menu_left_upper, text="info", height=70)
         self.group.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=TRUE)
         Button(self.menu_left_lower, text='Press', command=self.state).pack(side="bottom")
         self.w = Label(self.group, text='State='+self.stateVar)    #text printed!
         self.w.pack(expand=TRUE)

         # status bar
         self.status_frame = tk.Frame(root)
         self.status = tk.Label(self.status_frame, text=self.statusbar, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)    #statusbar printed here
         self.status.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
         self.menu_left.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")
         self.status_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")
         root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
         root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

 #Starts the main loop and causes the class to interact with the init function
 if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("simulation")
    app = Application(root)
    app.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Here you can see the whole code.

It's importend to check **# tab1** in there will be the button. This button refers to the **def state(self):** This one needs to change the label and the statusbar. wich are packed in **self.w** and **self.status** in the program I added a **#text printed!** after the line.

Comment: This too much code for a question this specific. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I reduced it a little. But the program won´t run if I make it smaller. I need some elements in it wich I want in my program. 
The important pieces of code are marked, you can read it in the last sentence what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example program that should help you figure out how to change the text of labels. They key thing is creating a StringVar and pointing the label towards this so that the label is updated when the StringVar is.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,**kw):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent,**kw)
        # Create a String variable to store our status string
        self.stateVar = StringVar()
        self.stateVar.set("Initial Value")

        # Create a label to display the status
        self.label1 = Label(textvariable=self.stateVar)
        self.label1.grid()

        # Create a button which will change the status
        self.button = Button(text="Press me", command=self.change)
        self.button.grid()

    def change(self):
        """Called when the button is pressed"""
        self.stateVar.set('You pressed the button')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("simulation")
    app = Application(root)
    app.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i needed! I already tried something very similair, but this works great. Thank you

Comment: You don't _have_ to use a `StringVar`. You can, but it's not strictly necessary. You can update labels directly.

Comment: Yep. `self.label1['text'] = "new string"` rather than `self.stateVar.set(...)` also works well

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the `Label` arguments: a tekst arguments is *not* updated if the input-variable is updated. You should assign the `stateVar` to the `Label`'s `textvariable` keyword argument and use no `text` argument.